# How can a transformer produce a high voltage and a low current?

Tags: electric-circuits

I understand that in ideal transformers, power is conserved. Because of this the product of voltage and current in the secondary winding is a constant.

This means that voltage and current are inversely related, which seems unintuitive because they are directly related by ohms law.

Shouldn't the emf induced in the secondary winding by the alternating magnetic flux be directly related to the current  by some constant, such as the resistance of the secondary winding?

I also came across a term known as impedance that seem to be related to the question. Wondering if it is of any relevance.

Comment: *"which seems unintuitive because they are directly related by ohms law"* - why are the secondary voltage and current related by Ohm's law?

Comment: Here's my reasoning: Primary coil induces an emf in secondary coil. Emf means a higher potential in the secondary coil which results in movement of electrons (current)

Comment: You are misapplying Ohm's Law. Ohm's Law describes the relationship between the instantaneous current flowing between two points on a metallic (or similar) _conductor_, and the voltage measured between those same two points at the same instant. Given an ideal AC voltage source connected to the primary of an ideal transformer, the secondary voltage will be determined by the the turns ratio of the transformer, and the current will be determined by the _load_.

Comment: The secondary current is the same as the load current. If the load is purely _resistive_ (i.e., _IF_ the load obeys Ohm's Law), and if you know its resistance value, then you use Ohm's Law to derive the current from the given voltage.

Comment: When you use a transformer to double the voltage to power a load, the transformer's "effective resistance" is 1/4 of the load's resistance.

Comment: Therefore if you apply the load's usual voltage on it, the current is four times what the load would use. But since we apply half the load's usual voltage, the current is only twice what the load uses at its usual voltage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that in ideal transformers, power is conserved. Because
>   of this the product of voltage and current in the secondary winding is
>   a constant.

This isn't true.  The expression of power conservation for an ideal transformer is

$$V_s\cdot I_s = V_p\cdot I_p$$

There is no requirement for $V_s\cdot I_s$ to be equal to a constant.

> This means that voltage and current are inversely related, which seems
>   unintuitive because they are directly related by ohms law.

Power conservation doesn't imply that the secondary voltage and current are inversely related.  Further, the secondary voltage and current (for an ideal transformer) are related by Ohm's law *only* if the load is a resistor but not otherwise.

For example, when the load is a resistor of resistance $R$ then...

- Ohm's Law
  $$V_s = R\cdot I_s,\quad V_s\cdot I_s = \frac{V^2_s}{R}$$
- Power conservation
  $$V_p \cdot I_p = V_s\cdot I_s$$
- Ideal transformer voltage relation
  $$V_s = N\cdot V_p$$

where $N = \frac{N_s}{N_p}$.  Thus

$$I_p = N^2\frac{V_p}{R} = \frac{V_p}{R/N^2}$$

That is, when the load is a resistor, both the primary *and* secondary voltage and current are related by Ohm's law *and* power is conserved.  See that the load resistance $R$ connected to the secondary appears as a resistance $R/N^2$ to the circuit connected to the primary.

> Shouldn't the emf induced in the secondary winding by the alternating
>   magnetic flux be directly related to the current by some constant,
>   such as the resistance of the secondary winding?

The resistance of the secondary winding is *zero* for an ideal transformer.  If the secondary winding has non-zero resistance, power conservation does not hold, i.e., the power delivered to the load is less than the power delivered to the primary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the emf induced per turn in both of the primary and secondary windings are equal due to the conservation of energy. Now if you increase the secondary windings with respect to the primary windings then you will get high voltage than the primary circuit for an ideal transformer. And consequently the current in the secondary windings will decrease following the fact underlies in the constancy of product of current and voltage in bother the windings. If any energy dissipative elements are present in those circuit, then you may convert the primary circuit referred to the secondary or vice versa and apply simply kcl and kvl and rigourously solve the resulting instantaneous equations. If the windings are not coupled to an extent such that magnetic flux leakage has become a serious issue , then the calculation will be quite difficult but not impossible.

Comment: That is fallacious reasoning.  If you have an ideal AC voltage source supplying the primary of an ideal transformer, and you have a fixed-value resistor as the load, then adding turns to the secondary will _increase_ the current in both windings.  It must do, because the secondary voltage is proportional to the number of secondary turns  (See the "Transformer Voltage Relation" in Alfred Centauri's answer), and Ohm's Law tells us that the current in the resistor (which equals the secondary current) is proportional to the voltage secondary voltage.

Comment: The current in a transformer's secondary is _proportional_ to the current in its primary, and the voltages are proportional as well. Where you get an inverse is between the two constants of proportionality.  If the turns ratio of the transformer is 1:3 and the primary voltage and current are 12 Volts and 3 Amps, then the secondary voltage and current will be 36V and 1A (36 W).  But if the primary voltage then is increased to 15V, the secondary voltage will go to 45V. And, if the load is a resistor, the secondary current will go to 1.25A, and the primary current will go to 3.75A (56.25 W).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an analogy which might help you grasp how a transformer works.

Think of an electrical transformer as if it were instead a car transmission. The ratio between torque and RPM at the input shaft is altered by the gears to yield a different ratio of torque to RPM at the output shaft.

As an example, in first gear the output shaft turns, say, at 1/4th the speed of the input shaft- but the torque at the output shaft is 4x that applied to the input shaft. the transmission "steps up" the torque and "steps down" the RPM, the torque ratio is 1:4 and the RPM ratio is 4:1.

Now remember that torque is analogous to voltage and RPM is analogous to current. Power is torque x RPM, so since power is conserved in the transmission, torque x RPM at the input shaft = torque x RPM at the output shaft and by analogy voltage x current at the primary winding = voltage x current at the secondary.

This means our transformer analog then steps current down by 1:4 and steps voltage up by 4:1.